# ¿cómo puedo sacar de una tabla de registro de pagos de otra tabla que tiene todas las personas que deben pagar?

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener de la tabla inquilinos los que no han cubierto el mes corriente, los pagos están dentro de otra tabla.

Estoy utilizando esta sentencia:

```sql
select distinct a.identificador
from catalogo_inmuebles a
inner join catalogo_inmuebles b on b.id_inmueble = a.id_inmueble
left join mantenimiento c on c.id_inmueble =b.id_inmueble
WHERE (c.mes_a_cubrir != 'febrero' AND c.anio_a_cubrir != '2024')
ORDER BY a.identificador
```

El resultado me arroja todos inquilinos y los meses que no son enero 2024, solo necesito un registro.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta que estás utilizando no seleccionará correctamente a los inquilinos que no han cubierto el mes corriente. El problema radica en la condición WHERE:

SQL
WHERE (c.mes_a_cubrir != 'febrero' AND c.anio_a_cubrir != '2024')
Usa el código con precaución.
Esta condición solo seleccionará registros donde el mes y el año no son "febrero" y "2024", respectivamente. Lo que necesitas es seleccionar registros donde el mes y el año son "febrero" y "2024", pero no existe un pago registrado.

Para lograr esto, puedes utilizar una subconsulta que verifique la existencia de un pago para el mes y año específicos:

```
SQL
SELECT DISTINCT a.identificador
FROM catalogo_inmuebles a
INNER JOIN catalogo_inmuebles b ON b.id_inmueble = a.id_inmueble
LEFT JOIN mantenimiento c ON c.id_inmueble = b.id_inmueble
WHERE a.identificador NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT d.identificador
  FROM catalogo_inmuebles d
  INNER JOIN mantenimiento e ON e.id_inmueble = d.id_inmueble
  WHERE e.mes_a_cubrir = 'febrero'
  AND e.anio_a_cubrir = '2024'
)
ORDER BY a.identificador;
```

Comment: Hola Alexis. Me ha servido perfectamente. Te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: hola, tengo otro problema que no he podido resolver por si solo, dentro del la consulta de deudores, tambien tengo que discreminar a los inquilinos que dentro del campo CONCEPTO tiene una anualidad vigente, las fechas de la anualidad esta dos campos fecha_inicial y fecha_final. Sugerencias por favor